# How to make the onclick Javascript element change text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I was wondering how to make an onclick element change text with a button.

The button code:

```
<a class="button" id="cool" style="text-decoration: none; color: white; font-family: cursive" 
onclick="document.getElementById('img').src='https://cdn.glitch.com/79c1be62-36ce-4443-9578-9779b5cb0a54%2Fterry-crews-person-of-year-2017-time-magazine-2.png?v=1619467585065'"
onclick="document.getElementById('cool').">make him cool?</a>
```

Please ignore the onclick style with the image, rather focus on the onclick element with the id "cool".

If I need to provide extra code as well let me know and I will do my best to provide it.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's three examples! The first one does it the way you wrote it -- with the function in the `onclick` attribute.

The second example shows how you can also use `this` instead of using `getElementById`, which is super useful especially if you copy the code into multiple places, since it references the element it's on directly instead of needing an ID.

Finally, the third example shows the recommended way to solve this problem -- passing `this` into an outside function. If you have a lot of extra code, you want to do this and not write the code directly into the `onclick` attribute to keep your HTML clean.

```js
function changeText(el) {
  el.innerHTML = "changed text";
}
```

```html
<a class="button" id="btn1" onclick="document.getElementById('btn1').innerHTML = 'changed text';">unchanged text</a>
<br>
<a class="button" onclick="this.innerHTML = 'changed text';">unchanged text</a>
<br>
<a class="button" onclick="changeText(this)">unchanged text</a>
```